# Circle symbols inside text - comparing available options

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to include solid and filled circles as part of the text block (indicating some kind of rating), as additional characters alongside to the text characters. See my first example below how I'd like to use them.

So far, I've found four options:

1. Use the math symbols `\circ` and `\bullet`:

   ```
   Lorem $\circ \circ \bullet$ ipsum
   ```
2. Using a `picture` environment of suitable size and `\put`ting a `\circle` where needed.
3. Use TikZ to have a symbol for a circle line and a filled circle, define them as commands and use them as needed.

   ```
   \newcommand{\textcirc}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \fill (0,0) circle [radius=0.3em];
    \end{tikzpicture}
   }
   \newcommand{\textbullet}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0,0) circle [radius=0.3em];
    \end{tikzpicture}
   }
   ```
4. Use Tikz to place the circles as nodes (node distance would need some tweaking):

   ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[draw,circle,radius=0.3em] (c1){};
   \node[circle,radius=0.3em, fill] (c2)[right of=c1]{};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   ```

Which of these options is the one which fits best to having a block of symbols inside the text? Is there another way to do what I want to do?

Comment: When you say "inside" the text, what do you mean?  In text mode, alongside of characters?  Overlaid inside of a character?  Also, would a scaled $\bullet$ suffice for the task?

Comment: In text mode, alongside of characters. I'll reorder my approaches and add an example.

Comment: Do you need something more than `Text \raisebox{-1pt}{\scalebox{1.6}{$\bullet$}} more text` where the `-1pt`  shift and `1.6` scale factor can be changed?  Note `\usepackage{graphic}` is required.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I think that this would do the trick, although I'd probably fiddle around with the spacing between the bullets.  What are the advantages of this approach in favor of using graphics blocks or graphic macros?

Comment: I'd go for the first option.

Comment: The advantage to using scaled-shifted-text symbols is quicker compilation, less code.  Also, a typo on my earlier comment...the package is `graphicx`.

Comment: Don't forget it's also easy to color the circles with features of the `xcolor` package: `\textcolor{blue!20}{...}`, where the `...` is your scaled/shifted bullet.

Comment: If you are using these in text, you might prefer to use *text* versions of the symbols which avoids the need to switch to maths mode. For example `\textbullet`. `\textcircled{a}` will give you a circled `a`. If you load the `textcomp` package, you also get `\textopenbullet`, `\textbigcircle` as well as other symbols.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the commands

```
\fullmoon
```

or

```
\newmoon
```

from the `wasysym` package, which show a circle or a filled circle respectively -- they should be identical to your request of a circle or 'bullet'.

By using

```
\fontsize{some_size_a}{some_size_b}
```

right before usage of the commands should scale your symbols.

I use `\newmoon` as an indicator for level of difficulty for my problem-solution package.

Comment: Is there any difference between these and `\Circle`/`\CIRCLE` from the same package? How do they differ from `\textcircle` and `\textopenbullet` from `textcomp`?

Comment: @Roland: 
 
As far as I got the right impression from the screen output, `\Circle` and `\CIRCLE` from the 'wasysym' package produce slightly larger symbols compared to the `\fullmoon` and `\newmoon` commands, whereas `textcircled{}` and `\textopenbullet` are either larger or smaller symbols, it is matter of taste only. By the way, did you mean `\textcircle` or `\textcircled`? There is a `pdf` file which contents a huge number of more or less useful symbols provided by various packages or fonts, available at www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf‎