# Draw cirle/point in text

Tags: text-decorations, circles

I want to (re-)construct circles and points within a paragraph (green). It looks like the circle is not the letter `o`.
In the lower part of the image I tried to highlight that the symbols are not regular letters because they do not stick to the base line (red horizantal line).

[image: Screenshot]

Can you give me some guidance how to achieve that?

Do not hesitate to leave a comment if you wish further details.

Comment: Can you show us a MWE with what you've tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160233/circle-symbols-inside-text-comparing-available-options/160512#160512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The dots (`$\bullet$') reprile the circles (`$\circ$')   %% math bullet

The dots (`\textbullet') reprile the circles (`$\circ$') %% text bullet
```

[image]

Comment: There's also `\textbullet`.

Comment: I would have kept the original `$\bullet$` but just reference the use of `\textbullet`.